# Remover números anterior a vírgula

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma sequência numérica em string tipo `'0,1;2,2;5,3;8,4;'`.

Preciso que o resultado saia `'1,2,3,4'` apenas os números após a virgula.

Já tentei a seguinte consulta:

```
{select replace(replace('0,1;2,2;5,3;8,4;', '[0-9'],', ''), ';', ',')}
```

Porém não substitui nada. Como faço para usar o operador que identifica qualquer numeral?

Comment: Talvez esse link possa ajudar - https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/SQL-Server/T-SQL/functions/regexp/index#:~:text=Apparently%2C%20SQL%20Server%20does%20not,create%20a%20regexp_replace()%20function.

Answer (score 1):

A solução que vou propor necessita que cada linha possua uma identificação única. Assim, para fins de demonstração da solução será considerada que essa identificação única existe.

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE tabela (ID_sequencia tinyint identity, Sequencia varchar(100));
INSERT into tabela values ('0,10;2,2;5,13;8,4');
go
```

Para separar os elementos será utilizada a função de usuário DelimitedSplit8K, de autoria de Jeff Moden. Informações sobre esta função estão disponíveis no artigo [An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function), sendo que o código fonte dela também pode ser obtido no artigo [Separar em partes uma lista de valores](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/separar-conteudo-de-texto-multivalorado_string-split/).

O primeiro passo é separar cada par:

```
-- código #2
SELECT ID_sequencia, T.sequencia, S1.ItemNumber as seqPar, S1.Item as Par
  from tabela as T 
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (T.sequencia, ';') as S1;
```

Após separar cada par, deve-se obter cada elemento de cada par:

```
-- código #3
with
gPar as (
SELECT ID_sequencia, T.sequencia, S1.ItemNumber as seqPar, S1.Item as Par
  from tabela as T 
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (T.sequencia, ';') as S1
),
gElemento as (
SELECT P.ID_Sequencia, P.sequencia, P.seqPar, 
       S2.ItemNumber as seqElemento, S2.Item as Elemento
  from gPar as P
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (P.Par, ',') as S2
)
SELECT ID_Sequencia, sequencia, seqPar, seqElemento, Elemento
  from gElemento 
  order by ID_Sequencia, seqPar;
```

Tendo-se cada elemento separado, o passo final é agrupar os elementos finais de cada par, na ordem de cada par. Eis o código SQL completo, utilizando a função STRING_AGG para agrupar os elementos:

```
-- código #4
-- Autor: José Diz 
with
gPar as (
SELECT ID_sequencia, T.sequencia, S1.ItemNumber as seqPar, S1.Item as Par
  from tabela as T 
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (T.sequencia, ';') as S1
),
gElemento as (
SELECT P.ID_Sequencia, P.sequencia, P.seqPar, 
       S2.ItemNumber as seqElemento, S2.Item as Elemento
  from gPar as P
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (P.Par, ',') as S2
)
SELECT ID_Sequencia, 
       string_agg (Elemento, ',') within group (order by seqPar)
  from gElemento
  where seqElemento = 2
  group by ID_Sequencia;
```

---

Como a função STRING_AGG somente funciona a partir da versão 2017 do SQL Server, ela pode ser substituída pela técnica *blackbox xml* nas versões anteriores do SQL Server. Detalhes no artigo [Concatenação de várias linhas de uma mesma coluna](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/01/05/funcao-string_agg/).

```
-- código #5 v2
-- Autor: José Diz 
with
gPar as (
SELECT ID_sequencia, T.sequencia, S1.ItemNumber as seqPar, S1.Item as Par
  from tabela as T 
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (T.sequencia, ';') as S1
),
gElemento as (
SELECT P.ID_Sequencia, P.sequencia, P.seqPar, 
       S2.ItemNumber as seqElemento, S2.Item as Elemento
  from gPar as P
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (P.Par, ',') as S2
)
SELECT E.ID_Sequencia, 
       --string_agg (Elemento, ',') within group (order by seqPar)
       stuff ((SELECT ',' + T.Elemento
                 from gElemento as T
                 where T.ID_Sequencia = E.ID_Sequencia
                       and T.seqElemento = 2
                 order by T.seqPar
                 for xml path(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
              1, 1, '') as novaSequencia       
  from gElemento as E
  where E.seqElemento = 2
  group by E.ID_Sequencia;
```